# Sails.js AND condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm using mongoDb with sails.js and need to make search by address string. For example -"Malibu 98000".
row in db look like this 
    {
        "state" : "CA",
        "streetNumber" : "120",
        "streetName" : "Sh",
        "city" : "Malibu",
        "zipCode" : "98000"
    }

But I'm not able to perform a waterline query using the "AND" condition. I've already tried it in several ways but most of them return empty or simply, never return.

```
    var propertySearchParams = {
       and : [
          or:[
               {streetNumber: {like: "%98000%"}},
               {zipCode: {like: "%98000%"}}
             ],
          or:[
               {streetName: {like: "%Malibu%"}},
               {city: {like: "%Malibu%"}},
               {state: {like: "%Malibu"}}
             ]
        ]
    }
```

How can I specify "Malibu" AND "98000"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you want the 'andWhere' modifier. Unfortunately there is no 'and' modifier in waterline for query params, but there is the `where()` function, which acts like `andWhere`.
So, basically, your query should look something like this:

```
Model.find()
     .where({
             or:[
               {streetNumber: {like: "%98000%"}},
               {zipCode: {like: "%98000%"}}
             ]
          })
    .where({
              or:[
               {streetName: {like: "%Malibu%"}},
               {city: {like: "%Malibu%"}},
               {state: {like: "%Malibu"}}
             ]
          })
    .exec(...);
```

Comment: ArVan, In above answer, only one where condition is working. Second where is overwriting the previous where. Please describe